# Problems with Angular routing. Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, angular-material

I'm using Angular material with routing. After a click event I want that my app will go to an URL which contains the parameter `currentUser`. The following is the click event in the app.component.html file:

```
<button mat-icon-button class="icon shopping cart-icon" aria-label="Icon-button with shopping cart icon" (click)="getCartByUser()"  [routerLink]="['/carts/cart_by_user/', currentUser]"  routerLinkActive="active">
    <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'carts/cart_by_user/:cartOfUser', component: CartComponent, pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The problem is that when I execute the app and the click event, the following error is displayed:

> Http failure response for
> http://localhost:8080/carts/cart_by_user/$%7Buser%7D: 400 OK

Error in the console:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
> URL Segment: 'carts/cart_by_user;id=9;code=000;...'

app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public currentUser!: User;
    public currentLogIn:boolean=false;
    constructor(private  shared: SharedService, private cartService:CartService){}
    ngOnInit():void {
        this.shared.castCart.subscribe(cart=>this.cart=cart);
        this.shared.castUser.subscribe(currentUser=>this.currentUser=currentUser);
        this.shared.castLoggedIn.subscribe(currentLogIn=>this.currentLogIn=currentLogIn);
  }

public getCartByUser():void{
    if(this.currentLogIn){
    this.cartService.getCartByUser(this.currentUser).subscribe(
      (response: Cart) => {
        this.cart=response;
        this.shared.setCart(this.cart);
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
    }

  }
```

shared.service.ts:

```
export class SharedService {
    public defaultCart!: Cart;
    private cart= new BehaviorSubject<Cart>(this.defaultCart);
    castCart = this.cart.asObservable();

    public defaultUser!: User;
    private user= new BehaviorSubject<User>(this.defaultUser);
    castUser = this.user.asObservable();

    private loggedIn= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    castLoggedIn = this.loggedIn.asObservable();

    setCart(data: Cart){
        this.cart.next(data);   }

    setUser(data: User){
        this.user.next(data);   }

    setLoggedIn(data:boolean){
        this.loggedIn.next(data);   }
}
```

cart.service.ts:

```
export class CartService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    public getCartByUser(user : User): Observable<Cart> {
        return this.http.get<Cart>('http://localhost:8080/carts/cart_by_user/${user}');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `currentUser` holds more than just string. It's an object, that has `id=9;code=000...` it can't find url ending with such params. How about just use the id of the user? Refactor places where your using url param `user` object to just `user.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

These are two different errors.

**Error 1**

> Http failure response for h​ttp://localhost:8080/carts/cart_by_user/$%7Buser%7D: 400 OK

Comes from cart.service.ts. You're attempting to use string interpolation using single quotes. If you want string interpolation you need to use backticks.

```js
export class CartService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    public getCartByUser(user : User): Observable<Cart> {
        return this.http.get<Cart>(`http://localhost:8080/carts/cart_by_user/${user}`);
    }
```

However, I don't know what the user object looks like, or what your api is expecting, so I have no idea if that will give you the proper get request.

**Error 2**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'carts/cart_by_user;id=9;code=000;...'

You can see there is a `/` missing after cart_by_user. I believe `routerLink` adds a `/` between path segments, which has probably escaped yours. Just remove the trailing `/`

```html
[routerLink]="['/carts/cart_by_user', currentUser]"
```